# wondering uf JSP page will ever be cached?

Tags: jsp

Use jsp to generate dynamic page. wondering of jsp will ever be cached or not? I am not using any expires or cache-control.

Comment: This is a too broad question. It boils down to "depends on the HTTP response headers which you or your server has set". Read this to learn about caching http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/.

Comment: I mean when server does not set anything.

Comment: It will set some defaults. As said, just check/change the response headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what @BalusC is referring to is get a sniffer and capture your the request to your jsp page on your server, You can get a add on to fire fox [http headers live](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/), once you install add on then open the add on by going fire fox ==> Tools ==> Live HTTP Headers, I printed an example capture here and these headers are easy to read. There are lot of other tools that do some thing similar.

```
         http://www.jsptut.com/Further.jsp

         //Request header
         GET /Further.jsp HTTP/1.1
         Host: www.jsptut.com
         User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
         Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
         Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
         Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
         Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
         Keep-Alive: 115
         Connection: keep-alive
         Referer: http://www.jsptut.com/
         Cookie: JSESSIONID=ds43d6a9a50050pqfv61h
         Cache-Control: max-age=0

         //Response Header from server
         HTTP/1.1 200 OK
         Server: Blazix Java Server 1.2
         Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2011 17:49:30 GMT
         Content-Type: text/html
         Transfer-Encoding: chunked
         Via: 1.1 xx.xx.xx:80 
         Connection: keep-alive
```